# Cannot display value in select element

Tags: javascript

The second Select element cannot display the countries dynamically, I have follow the tutorial exactly but wonder why it simply won't work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var citieslist=document.classic.subj2

var cities=new Array()
cities[0]=""
cities[1]=["New York|newyorkvalue", "Los Angeles|loangelesvalue", "Chicago|chicagovalue", "Houston|houstonvalue", "Austin|austinvalue"]
cities[2]=["Vancouver|vancouvervalue", "Tonronto|torontovalue", "Montreal|montrealvalue", "Calgary|calgaryvalue"]
cities[3]=["London|londonvalue", "Glasgow|glasgowsvalue", "Manchester|manchestervalue", "Edinburgh|edinburghvalue", "Birmingham|birminghamvalue"]

function updateSubj(selectedcitygroup){
    citieslist.options.length=0
    if (selectedcitygroup>0){
        for (i=0; i<cities[selectedcitygroup].length; i++)
        citieslist.options[citieslist.options.length]=new Option(cities[selectedcitygroup][i].split("|")[0], cities[selectedcitygroup][i].split("|")[1])
    }
}
</script>
<div id="template">
    <div id="links">
        <li><a href=".">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href=".">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href=".">Request</a></li>
        <li><a href=".">Cloud</a></li>
        <li><a href=".">Pricing</a></li>
    </div>
    <img id="tta" src="tta/tta.png"></img>
    <div id="picture"></div>
    <div id="search">
    <img id="tta" src="tta/search.jpg"></img>
    <form name="classic">
    <p>LEVEL</p>
    <select onChange="updateSubj(this.selectedIndex)">
        <option>Select A City</option>
        <option>USA</option>
        <option>Canada</option>
        <option>United Kingdom</option>
    </select>
    <p>SUBJECT</p>
    <select name="subj2"></select>
    <p>TYPE</p>
    <select name="sasd"></select>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="gradient_bg"></div>
    <?php
    echo "ssssss";
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

While this tutorial work.

```
<form name="classic">
 <select onChange="updateSubj(this.selectedIndex)">
     <option>Select A City</option>
     <option>USA</option>
 </select>

 <select name="subj"></select>
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 var clist=document.classic.subj

 var cities2=new Array()
 cities2[0]=""
 cities2[1]=["New York|newyorkvalue"]
 cities2[2]=["Vancouver|vancouvervalue"]


 function updateSubj(ssg){
    clist.options.length=0
    if (ssg>0){

        for (i=0; i<cities2[ssg].length; i++)
            clist.options[clist.options.length]=new Option(cities2[ssg][i].split("|")[0], cities2[ssg][i].split("|")[1])
        }
 }

 </script>
```

Comment: Please, edit you question and only place necessary. It is not really helpful, if you paste your entire HTML document.

Comment: Uch, you got that from a tutorial? Probably dating from 1999? There's a lot wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var citieslist=document.classic.subj2` is declared before the element exists, it's also a lot better to do the following instead.

```
var citiesList = document.getElementById( "subj2" );
```

And make sure that the script runs once your needed HTML elements are available. An easy (and just best) way to do this is to include all javascript at the bottom of your document before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: However, the tutorial work and my code doesn't work? Strange? I have cut and paste exactly for 10 times. That more difficult than Actionscript.

Comment: The tutorial has the script below the target HTML, while you have it BEFORE the HTML. When creating references to HTML, the HTML needs to be before the script. It's a matter of ordering.

Comment: OMG! It works! I remember someone has the same issue 3 years ago. Still the ordering make no sense till today. Hehe.

Comment: No need to place code anywhere but in the head here. See my suggestion

Comment: @MPlungjan aye better code, but putting scripts at the bottom is good nontheless, HTML will render faster because it won't have to wait for script to complete and no need for domReady implementations and whatnot. It's just good practise ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version. Note that I do not need to save the select before the script runs

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var cities=new Array()
cities[0]=[];
cities[1]=["New York|newyorkvalue", "Los Angeles|loangelesvalue", "Chicago|chicagovalue", "Houston|houstonvalue", "Austin|austinvalue"]
cities[2]=["Vancouver|vancouvervalue", "Tonronto|torontovalue", "Montreal|montrealvalue", "Calgary|calgaryvalue"]
cities[3]=["London|londonvalue", "Glasgow|glasgowsvalue", "Manchester|manchestervalue", "Edinburgh|edinburghvalue", "Birmingham|birminghamvalue"]

function updateSubj(countrySel){
  var selectedcitygroup = countrySel.selectedIndex;
  var citieslist = countrySel.form.citieslist;
  citieslist.options.length=0;
  if (selectedcitygroup>0){
    for (var i=0; i<cities[selectedcitygroup].length; i++) {
      var parts = cities[selectedcitygroup][i].split("|");
      citieslist.options[citieslist.options.length]=new Option(parts[0], parts[1])
    }
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="template">
    <div id="links">
        <li><a href=".">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href=".">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href=".">Request</a></li>
        <li><a href=".">Cloud</a></li>
        <li><a href=".">Pricing</a></li>
    </div>
    <img id="tta" src="tta/tta.png"></img>
    <div id="picture"></div>
    <div id="search">
    <img id="tta" src="tta/search.jpg"></img>
    <form name="classic">
    <p>LEVEL</p>
    <select name="country" onChange="updateSubj(this)">
        <option>Select a country</option>
        <option>USA</option>
        <option>Canada</option>
        <option>United Kingdom</option>
    </select>
    <p>SUBJECT</p>
    <select name="citieslist"></select>
    <p>TYPE</p>
    <select name="sasd"></select>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="gradient_bg"></div>
    <?php
    echo "ssssss";
    ?>
</div>
</body>
```